# How to select part of the string with T-SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a string comma delimited. I need to select with t-sql just first part of it.

Example

table

```
id                   items                              values    
1                    item, item2, item3, item4          5
```

I need to get result like

```
ID                    Items             Values
1                     item              5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
select id, 
       substring(items,0,charindex(',',items)),
       values 
from mytable
```

Comment: If `items` contains just one item, this query returns empty string. If it must return the single item, change the `CHARINDEX` expression like this: `...CHARINDEX(',', items + ',')...`.